# Properly 'Joining' two Cross Applies

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply

I've got a query with three Cross-Applies that gather data from three different tables. The first Cr-Ap assists the 2nd and 3rd Cr-Ap's. It finds the most recent ID of a certain refill for a 'cartridge', the higher the ID the more recent the refill.

The second and third Cr-Ap's gather the SUMS of items that have been refilled and items that have been dispensed under the most recent Refill.

If I run the query for Cr-Ap 2 or 3 separately the output would look something like:

```
ID      Amount
1       100
2       1000
3       100
4       0
5       0
etc
```

Amount would be either the amount of dispensed or refilled items.

Only I don't want to run these queries separately, I want them next to each other.
So what I want is a table that looks like this:

```
ID      Refill      Dispense
1       100         1
2       1000        5
3       100         7
4       0           99
5       0           3
etc
```

My gut tells me to do

```
INNER JOIN crossaply2 ON crossapply3.ID = crossapply2.ID
```

But this doesn't work. I'm still new to SQL so I don't exactly know what I can and can't join, what I do know is that you can use crossapply as a join (sorta?). I think that might be what I need to do here, I just don't know how.

But that's not it, there's another complication, there are certain refills where nothing gets dispensed. In these scenarios the crossapply I wrote for dispenses won't return anything for that refillID. With nothing I don't mean NULL, I mean it just skips the refillID. But I'd like to see a 0 in those cases. Because it just skips over those ID's I can't get COALESCE or ISNULL to work, this might also complicate the joining of these two applies. Because an INNER JOIN would skip any line where there is no Dispensed amount, even though there is a Refilled amount Id like to see.
Here is my code:

```
-- Dispensed SUM and Refilled SUM combined
SELECT [CartridgeRefill].[FK_CartridgeRegistration_Id]
    ,Refills.Refilled
    ,Dispenses.Dispensed
FROM [CartridgeRefill]
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT MAX([CartridgeRefill].[Id]) AS RecentRefillID
    FROM [CartridgeRefill]
    GROUP BY [CartridgeRefill].[FK_CartridgeRegistration_Id]
) AS RecentRefill
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT [CartridgeRefill].[FK_CartridgeRegistration_Id] AS RefilledID
        ,SUM([CartridgeRefillMedication].[Amount]) AS Refilled
    FROM [CartridgeRefillMedication]
    INNER JOIN [CartridgeRefill] ON [CartridgeRefillMedication].[FK_CartridgeRefill_Id] = [CartridgeRefill].[Id]
    WHERE [CartridgeRefillMedication].[FK_CartridgeRefill_Id] = RecentRefill.RecentRefillID
    GROUP BY [CartridgeRefill].[FK_CartridgeRegistration_Id]
) AS Refills
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT [CartridgeRefill].[FK_CartridgeRegistration_Id] AS DispensedID
        ,SUM([CartridgeDispenseAttempt].[Amount]) AS Dispensed
    FROM [CartridgeDispenseAttempt]
    INNER JOIN [CartridgeRefill] ON [CartridgeDispenseAttempt].[FK_CartridgeRefill_Id] = [CartridgeRefill].[Id]
    WHERE [CartridgeDispenseAttempt].[FK_CartridgeRefill_Id] = RecentRefill.RecentRefillID
    GROUP BY [CartridgeRefill].[FK_CartridgeRegistration_Id]
) AS Dispenses
GO
```

The output of this code is as follows:

```
1   300 1
1   300 1
1   200 194
1   200 194
1   200 8
1   200 8
1   0   39
1   0   39
1   100 14
1   100 14
1   200 1
1   200 1
1   0   28
1   0   28
1   1000    102
1   1000    102
1   1000    557
1   1000    557
1   2000    92
1   2000    92
1   100 75
1   100 75
1   100 100
1   100 100
1   100 51
1   100 51
1   600 28
1   600 28
1   200 47
1   200 47
1   200 152
1   200 152
1   234 26
1   234 26
1   0   227
1   0   227
1   10  6
1   10  6
1   300 86
1   300 86
1   0   194
1   0   194
1   500 18
1   500 18
1   1000    51
1   1000    51
1   1000    56
1   1000    56
1   500 48
1   500 48
1   0   10
1   0   10
1   1500    111
1   1500    111
1   56  79
1   56  79
1   100 6
1   100 6
1   44  134
1   44  134
1   1000    488
1   1000    488
1   100 32
1   100 32
1   100 178
1   100 178
1   500 672
1   500 672
1   200 26
1   200 26
1   500 373
1   500 373
1   100 10
1   100 10
1   900 28
1   900 28
2   900 28
2   900 28
2   900 28
etc
```

It is total nonsense that I can't do much with, it goes on for about 20k lines and goes through all the ID's, eventually.
Any help is more than appreciated :)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: First of all I think the first Cross Apply section is missing the where clause so there is a full table join between it and the main query section (and probably in more).  Also, what is the relation between CartridgeRefill columns ID and FK_CartridgeRefill_ID ?  The base table structure would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like overcomplicated a bit.
Try

```
WITH cr AS (
    SELECT [FK_CartridgeRegistration_Id]
       ,MAX([CartridgeRefill].[Id])  RecentRefillID
    FROM [CartridgeRefill] 
    GROUP BY [FK_CartridgeRegistration_Id]
)
SELECT cr.[FK_CartridgeRegistration_Id],  Refills.Refilled, Dispenses.Dispensed
FROM cr 
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT SUM(crm.[Amount]) AS Refilled
    FROM [CartridgeRefillMedication] crm
    WHERE crm.[FK_CartridgeRefill_Id] = cr.RecentRefillID
) AS Refills
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT SUM(cda.[Amount]) AS Dispensed
    FROM [CartridgeDispenseAttempt] cda
    WHERE cda.[FK_CartridgeRefill_Id] = cr.RecentRefillID
) AS Dispenses;
```

Comment: Wow! That worked exactly the way I wanted, thanks :)